# Bad fadeout/load/fadein/scrollto after clicking in a table to get an ID

Tags: javascript, load, fadein, fadeout, scrollto

I have an odd problem with JavaScript: After clicking in a table (to get an ID of the selected row), the loaded url below should be **[faded out](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)**, then it should **[load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)** the new url with the new ID(s), then a **[fade-in](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)** with the new site and finally **[scroll to](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)** the div, which contains the new url.

BUT with this code it doesn't work. 1. It's fading out. 2. It's fading in (with the old url!). 3. It's scrolling to the div-id. 4. It's loading the new url. (sometimes 3 and 4 together)

```
$("#mydivid").fadeOut('slow', function() {
$("#mydivid").load("/url.php", { \"id1\": id1, \"id2\": id2 }).fadeIn('slow');});                   
$(window).scrollTo('#mydivid', {duration:2500} );
```

I don't think the table is the problem here, that's why I avoid to show the related code. The loaded "url.php" is a big file (but only with HTML-Text and Canvas-Pictures) - could that be the problem?

Comment: _The loaded "url.php" is a big a file ... could that be the problem?_ . In this case, yes. php still loading whrn you call fadeIn

Comment: loading the url takes time, perhaps listen for an event that fires when the url is loaded and attach the `fadein` to _that_ callback instead.